# How to calculate sample size of a study with difference in median as primary outcomes

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, median

A quick question on sample size calculation. How to calculate the sample size for a study in which the primary outcome is a difference in the median time to improvement (e.g. 10 median days in group A vs. 8 median days in group B?)

Normaly this is done with mean, but whatever. Is there a way?
Thanks in advance.